# Laravel 5.2 get response from Mail (MailGun, Mandrill, Sendgrid or whatever)

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, sendgrid

How can I get the Laravel Mail class response?

I am working with Sendgrid and I know that when I "ask" it to send an email it gives me back a MSGID and I would like to get it to keep in my database but the Laravel Mail class does not give any response!

Somebody knows how to do that?

---------------- EDITING FROM HERE

Actually I am gonna improve my question =)

I need to work with webhooks to know when the e-mail is delivered, opened and clicked!

How can I link the webhook received from Sendgrid with the emails on my "sent_mails" database table?

By the Sendgrid Panel I find a MSGID that is equals for every action from a specific e-mail but I don't have that ID on my base to link it!

Comment: There's no way to do it from there, but you can take advantage of Sendgrid's web hooks: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

Comment: @aynber I kind of changed my question! Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: You can try to link it another way, such as email address/subject/time combination. It depends on what information they pass back as it compares to what you've stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news!

For SendGrid at least just found a good solution!

We can add custom fields when send an email and those fields will be on the webhook sent from SenGrid to you application!

So you can add a custom field with the ID of your record and it will be on the post data sent back to you by webhook =)

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html

Easy!! Hope it helps someone else as well!